# How to solve TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference while calling swf from flex 3

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flash-cs3

I'm new to flash . I have called this flash code in Flex using SWF loader .I got the following Error. Here I've attached flash coding for header_text_fla Kindly do the needful.

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference. at header_text_fla::MainTimeline/loaderComplete()

```
var myEvent:Event;
var myParams:LoaderInfo;
function loaderComplete(myEvent:Event)
{
if(this.loaderInfo.parameters.text1 != null)
{
Text1.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.text1 as String;
}
if(this.loaderInfo.parameters.text2 != null)
{
Text2.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.text2 as String;
}
if(this.loaderInfo.parameters.text3 != null)
{
Text3.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.text3 as String;
}
}

function useParams()
{

}

var myLoaderInfo=new Object();
myLoaderInfo.myParamsLoaded=false;
myLoaderInfo.loaderComplete=loaderComplete;
myLoaderInfo.useParams=useParams;

this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, myLoaderInfo.loaderComplete );
```

Comment: The code is very confusing. You're using references to 'myLoaderInfo' as well as 'loaderInfo'. The six lines of code at the bottom also appear to be not encapsulated in anything, which confuses me. While a variable declaration is acceptable not encapsulated in a function, the property setters and eventlistener registration shouldn't be unencapsulated like that.

Comment: Can you give us the line that the debugger is saying is responsible? There are lot of things you are accessing here that would throw this, and this may not even be the code responsible. This is why compilers/debuggers give a line reference or at the very least a block reference of where the error occurred.

Comment: This I am used to get the flashvars data from flex and used in swf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by using try catch.Here is the code

```
try
{
    Text1.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.text1 as String;
    Text2.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.text2 as String;
    Text3.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.text3 as String;
}
catch(error:Error)
{
    trace("Error");
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

:-) Nice code.

Please write:

```
function loaderComplete(myEvent:Event)
{
if (!this.loaderInfo) trace ("no loader info");
if (!this.loaderInfo.parameters) trace ("no loader info parameters");
if (!Text1) trace ("no Text1");
if (!Text2) trace ("no Text2");
if (!Text3) trace ("no Text3");
...
YOUR CODE HERE
...
```

This will give you the object that is not initialized and responsible for the error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

What could be the problem is that you are using a temporary object's (myLoaderInfo) function as an event handler. Since the object is temporary (or at least seems to be in the code given above), and the event is sent asynchronously, the garbage collector might clean the myLoaderInfo instance before the function is called making it null and causing the error when the callback function is called.

Try making your myLoaderInfo a class parameter :

```
var myEvent      : Event;
var myParams     : LoaderInfo;
var myLoaderInfo : Object;//added myLoaderInfo here

function loaderComplete(myEvent:Event)
{
    if(this.loaderInfo.parameters.text1 != null)
    {
        Text1.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.text1 as String;
    }
    if(this.loaderInfo.parameters.text2 != null)
    {
        Text2.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.text2 as String;
    }
    if(this.loaderInfo.parameters.text3 != null)
    {
        Text3.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.text3 as String;
    }
}

function useParams()
{
}

myLoaderInfo = new Object();
myLoaderInfo.myParamsLoaded = false;
myLoaderInfo.loaderComplete = loaderComplete;
myLoaderInfo.useParams      = useParams;

this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, myLoaderInfo.loaderComplete );
```

That way, the garbage collector won't clean it up.